# Using .hpp Header Files from OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, header-files, face-detection

I am new to OpenCV and I am currently working on a Java project concerning Face Detection.
 I came across this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) which is in c++  and the one place i got stuck at is the .hpp files.

I tried running this code in Turbo C++ but it says unable to open include file 'opencv2/highgui.hpp' and likewise for all the hpp files.

To resolve the error
1) I copied the opencv2 folder from C:\OpenCV-2.4.7\opencv\build\include to C:\turbo\tc\bi\include which is my INCLUDE Directory as specified in the Options>Directories of Turbo C++.

Can we specify multiple INCLUDE Paths in Turbo c++?
 Please tell a way to include these hpp files so that the c++ code executes..I know the problem is with the folders path, but I'm not able to resolve the issue any further.
Thanks!

Comment: I think the header location is #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" and you can add all OpenCV header with single header file opencv2/opencv.hpp

Comment: turbo c++ ? i highly doubt , you can use that. also, don't copy header files around, instead adjust your include path

Comment: @Haris No, what I am not able to do is to get the Turbo C++ to look into the path where opencv2 folder is..It just looks in the C:\tc\bin\INCLUDE directory (that's specified in Options Menu)

Comment: @Berak That's exactly what I was asking, adjusting the include path or do you mean to say that we cant do so in Turbo?

Comment: if you wnt to use turboc++, you've got a larger problem. as no precopiled opencv libs exist for that, you'll have to recompile opencv from src, using cmake. and there's no option to generate something for turboc++ there.

Comment: i just don't think, it's possible at all. get a decent compiler.

Comment: which compiler do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find where is your opencv.hpp file, on linux the easier is to run:

```
# find / -name opencv.hpp
```

This will give you the path for your opencv files.

Consider the path where you placed you OpenCV. -- e.g. C:\Program Files\OpenCV\include . The path may change according to the way you installed the OpenCV and according to your operational system.

In linux you should include the path to your profile. For that you can use bash_profile or bashrc.
http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

One way to do it is like:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv.hpp"
```

You can also specify the paths for hpp or any other files in your make file.

Here some examples:

http://www.digitalpeer.com/id/example

http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/libraries.html

Comment: Avanz! I am using a windows 8..Sorry I forgot to specify this. Is there a windows specific solution? Also note that I know the location of opencv.hpp file, the only problem is to get the turbo compiler to look into both- the include folder in tc\bin and the one in opencv\build\include

Comment: The command find is from linux/unix. Both in *nix and windows, you can specify the libs/hpp in your make file. If you are using a IDE, then you have to check your project lib specification. In my opinion a good if you have to use some IDE for programming, is to adopt Eclipse.